# Excel VBA formula equivalent?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a VBA equivalent of (and pardon my poor formuala but I think it gets the point across) of IF(ISNA(D2:K2),"Nothing found",="value of first cell without #N/A" in it"

In other words, iterate through rows D through K, and when I find the first cell w/o an error, use the value in that cell.

```
Sub ValueNotError
   Dim oRng1 As Range
   Dim oRNg2 As Range
   Dim oWs1 As Worksheet
   Dim oWs2 As Worksheet
   Dim X As Integer
' Set initial cell
Set oWs1 = This Workbook.Worsheets("Master")
Set oRng2 = oWs2.Range ("D2")
Set oRng1 = oWs2.Range ("C2")
   Do Until IsEmpty(oRng1) ' Look until column D has no value?
       If IsError(oRng1.Offset(0,1).Value Then ' Look to see if cell is error
           For X = 10 to 1 Step -1 ' Work from K descending
              If Not IsError (oRng1.Offset(0,X).Value Then
              oRng2.Value = oRng1.Value ' set oRng1 to oRng2 value
              oRng2 = oRng2.offset(1,0) ' move to next row
              Exit For
           End If
      Next X
      Else
           Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1,0) ' Move to next row
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: use `.find` then you can use the return of `nothing` to see if it was there.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-find-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA? Here's a formula only solution that will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D2:K2,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISERROR(D2:K2),),0)),"Nothing found")
```

You could also use conditional formatting to simply highlight the first non-error cell found in the range.  With the cells D2:K2 selected, use this conditional format formula:

```
=AND(COLUMN(D2)-3=MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR($D2:$K2),0),NOT(ISERROR(D2)))
```

Note that you could apply the conditional format formula to a range including multiple rows, such as D2:K12 and it would highlight the first non-error value in each row.

Comment: That works well, thanks! The last part is a separate question so I'll post it